# Hide EMA Cloud fill below certain timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I have a code for an ema cloud, which i want only to appear on 15m and above timeframes, help would be much appreciated ;)

The code:

```
ema50 = ta.ema(hl2, 50)
ema75 = ta.ema(hl2, 75)

ema1 = plot(ema50, color=color.new(#2e39cc, 100), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
ema2 = plot(ema75, color=color.new(#2a2e39, 97), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)


fill(ema1, ema2, color=ema50 > ema75 ? #cbe2de : #eacccc, editable=true, transp=55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `f_resInMinutes()` function below to check if your chart is on 15 min and above. Then plot your EMA lines only if that's the case.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_resInMinutes() => 
    _resInMinutes = timeframe.multiplier * (
      timeframe.isseconds ? 1. / 60             :
      timeframe.isminutes ? 1.                  :
      timeframe.isdaily   ? 60. * 24            :
      timeframe.isweekly  ? 60. * 24 * 7        :
      timeframe.ismonthly ? 60. * 24 * 30.4375  : na)

is_15_and_above = f_resInMinutes() >= 15

ema50 = ta.ema(hl2, 50)
ema75 = ta.ema(hl2, 75)

ema1 = plot(is_15_and_above ? ema50 : na, color=color.new(#2e39cc, 100), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)
ema2 = plot(is_15_and_above ? ema75 : na, color=color.new(#2a2e39, 97), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1)


fill(ema1, ema2, color=ema50 > ema75 ? #cbe2de : #eacccc, editable=true, transp=55)
```